# VB2010 Get Mouse Position On Form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

i currently have a form that is not maximized. I have some code in the MouseDown sub that when i click on the form, it will give me a msgbox that has the mouse click position. The problem is that when i move the form and click at the same location, it does not give me the same location. It is giving me the position of the window screen, not the form. Is there a way i can fix this?

Code:

```
sub MouseDown.......

msgbox Mouseposition.x & ", " & mouseposition.y
end sub
```

Comment: Please make a minimal effort to post accurate code.  Use the form's PointToClient() method.

Comment: @HansPassant: Maybe PointToScreen could be more useful in this case? MouseDown provides client coordinates already.

Comment: To OP: please provide more information about your problem (some VB.NET code). How you handle MouseDown event. Which coordinates you get, which coordinates you expect to get, how the form is moved relative to its original position (screenshots).

Comment: That is accurate code, that code actually works, except for the sub mousedown part, i didn't want to type the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want **client coords** use `e.X` and `e.Y`:

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown
    MessageBox.Show(e.X & ", " & e.Y)
End Sub
```