# Get Mouse Position in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I need to get the X Y coordinates of the console (CMD) in VBScript
Where "Z" has the result of `1 = right mouse button` and `2 = left button`

X & Y = Normal coordinates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB2010 Get Mouse Position On Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27426534/vb2010-get-mouse-position-on-form)

Comment: Is VBScript, nothing VB.net :(

Comment: Not possible in VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that this is unanswered !

Did no one tried the following code in vbscript ?

```
DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("System.Windows.Forms.Control").MousePosition.X
DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("System.Windows.Forms.Control").MousePosition.Y
```